# How can I get record max length of prefix with minimum cost?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table **price**.

Which have total 4 fields like

```
+----+--------------+----------+------------+  
| Id | Prefix       |  rate    |  Ref_id  
+----+--------------+----------+------------+    
| 1  |     51       |    0.30  |    2      
| 2  |     51888    |    0.20  |    2    
| 3  |     51       |    0.10  |    1    
| 4  |     5188     |    0.10  |    1    
| 5  |     518      |    0.10  |    1
```

Now i want to get the record with maximum length prefix value with each Ref_id.

So in Ref_id 2 has total 2 no of prefix but have longest prefix value is

```
+----+--------------+----------+------------+
| Id | Prefix       |  rate    |  Ref_id  
+----+--------------+----------+------------+  
| 2  |   51888      | 0.20     | 2
```

and Ref_id 1 has total 3 no of prefix and have longest prefix is

```
+----+--------------+----------+------------+
| Id | Prefix       |  rate    |  Ref_id
+----+--------------+----------+------------+
| 4  |     5188     |    0.10  |    1
```

After this two value , it must short internally and return the final output like

```
+----+--------------+----------+------------+
| Id | Prefix       |  rate    |  Ref_id
+----+--------------+----------+------------+
| 4  |     5188     |    0.10  |    1
| 2  |     51888    |    0.20  |    2
```

because it will get each Ref_id longest prefix with least cost.

I did try but getting like only longest prefix but not able to get longest prefix and then sorting of that value with least rate.

Comment: Is this matching phone numbers to prefixes?

Comment: What is the data type of prefix? Is it varchar or int?

Comment: prefix datatype is varchar and first it should get longest prefix of each Ref_id and once get that value it should get lowest rate value.

Comment: I edited question, please check and update answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've made certain assumptions - but you get the idea...

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM price x
  JOIN
     ( SELECT ref_id, MAX(LENGTH(prefix)) longest FROM price GROUP BY ref_id ) y
    ON y.ref_id = x.ref_id 
   AND y.longest = LENGTH(x.prefix)
 ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by with inner query, e.g.:

```
    select ref_id as id, 
    (select prefix from price where ref_id = id order by length(prefix) desc limit 1) as prefix,
(select min(rate) from price where ref_id = id) as rate
        from price
        group by ref_id
        order by prefix
```

Comment: I think the OP wants the longest string - which is not necessarily the one with the largest value.

Comment: @Strawberry is correct, take 00001 for example, its smaller then 10

Comment: We don't know the type of prefix column. Anyway, I have updated my answer to take length into consideration.

Comment: We can infer the type by the alignment. Besides, the OP appears to want to return the whole row.

Comment: but what about lowest rate for each Ref_id ?

Comment: I suspect that it might be better to use one of the other answers provided.